# Trying to link Wordpress media image getting error message and /#prettyphoto added to URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, image

I am trying to link numerous images on my site to other internal pages using the method described by Wordpress employing the Custom URL target in Image Details.

When the image is clicked on website, an error message is received indicating the image cannot load (which I don't want anyway) and the resulting page URL suddenly has a "#!prettyPhoto" appended to the page URL. How do I get the link to work and get rid of the append?

Comment: there might be an attribute in the image link - `rel="prettyphoto"` - you will have to remove that - I had the same issue once and this solved it for me.

Comment: I don't see that attribute in the body HTML.  Would the attribute be located somewhere else?  I am weak on code so if you could be specific it would be helpful. Thxs for your help.

Comment: <a href="http://airtechscreens.com/request-quote"><img class="alignnone wp-image-521 size-full" src="http://airtechscreens.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/RequestQuote.gif" alt="Request a retractable screen quote from Air Tech Screen" width="133" height="31" /></a>

Comment: @MichaelDoye - I found reference that rel="prettyphoto" attribute in jquery.prettyPhoto.js file and changed the deeplinking value from true to false.  Unfortunately, that did not work. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelDoye - just a brief note that I was able to solve the issue by adding a class="nolightbox" to the code... works like a charm.            <a href="http://airtechscreens.com/request-quote" class="noLightbox"><img class="size-full wp-image-521" src="http://airtechscreens.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/RequestQuote.gif" alt="Request a retractable screen quote from Air Tech Screen" width="133" height="31" /></a>

Comment: @Ihilton760 apologies for the delayed response! Thats great!